# Emacs: annoying Flymake dialog box

Tags: c++, emacs, elisp, flymake

I have the following lines in my `~/.emacs.d/init.el`

```el
(custom-set-variables
  '(flymake-allowed-file-name-masks 
    (quote 
      (
        ("\\.cc\\'" flymake-simple-make-init) 
        ("\\.cpp\\'" flymake-simple-make-init)))))
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'flymake-find-file-hook)
```

When I open a C++ file that has a proper Makefile in the same folder, I get on-the-fly compilation and error reporting (Flymake will check the syntax and report errors and warnings during code editing).

The Makefile has a `check-syntax` target:

```
.PHONY: check-syntax
check-syntax:
 $(CXX) -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fsyntax-only $(CHK_SOURCES)
```

The problem is that when I open a .cc file that has no corresponding Makefile I get an annoying dialog box that warns me about flymake being disabled.

So if I launch `emacs *.cc` in a folder with 20 C++ files I get 20 **modal** dialog boxes saying something like *No buildfile found for [...]. Flymake will be switched off*.

Is there some hook I can use to disable that warning? Can you provide sample elisp code and explanation on how you found the proper hook?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Easiest way to do this, and still recieve the messages, is to leave the customization variable set to true, and redefine the flymake-display-warning function.

```el
;; Overwrite flymake-display-warning so that no annoying dialog box is
;; used.

;; This version uses lwarn instead of message-box in the original version. 
;; lwarn will open another window, and display the warning in there.
(defun flymake-display-warning (warning) 
  "Display a warning to the user, using lwarn"
  (lwarn 'flymake :warning warning))

;; Using lwarn might be kind of annoying on its own, popping up windows and
;; what not. If you prefer to recieve the warnings in the mini-buffer, use:
(defun flymake-display-warning (warning) 
  "Display a warning to the user, using lwarn"
  (message warning))
```

Comment: I would override the function with `defadvice` rather than `defun`, since the former explicitly declares your intent to override the function, and it also works even if flymake is re-loaded later.

Comment: since that wouldn't be exactly equivalent (ie. `s/defun/defadvice/` is not sufficent), can you post it as an answer @RyanThompson

Answer (score 11):

There is a variable that can be customized and that I overlooked.

`flymake-gui-warnings-enabled`

This will disable any GUI message, but I'll be fine with it if no one will post a better answer.

Comment: it seems this disables all the warnings/error messages from flymake. The best way would be to show the messages in minibuffer.